# How can I use DAX and get Rank Function Working?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I am trying to follow the example here.

https://www.sumproduct.com/blog/article/power-pivot-principles/ppp-introducing-the-rankx-function

I created a table named 'MyRanks', which looks like this.

[image]

If I enter '=RANKX(MyRanks,[Total Sales])', nothing happens.

When I go to PowerPivot and Calculated Fields, then I enter '=RANKX(MyRanks,[Total Sales])', I get an error saying, 'The name you entered is not valid.'

[image]

Finally, when I select the table and click Calculated Fields and New Calculated Field, I get this error.

[image]

When I look at YouTube videos, it always works fine for people. When I try to do it, it never works for me. Not sure if something is not setup right, or what's going on here. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DAX functions don't work directly from excel sheets. You can use it with data models built of Power Query M data model, or in linkback tables request, but the functionality is still very limited and you will have hard time finding what exactly does or doesn't work in excel. DAX is predominantly a Power Bi feature

Comment: I think you are entering the formula in the wrong place. After you go to Power Pivot, you may see a table with a grayed out column labelled "Add Column".  Select that column, then write your formula into the formula bar.

Comment: I guess, it's something like that. Still not working though. Oh, well. I am just trying to learn a new trick for my bag of tricks. Anyway, the Rank function works just fine. Thanks guys, for trying to help!!